# Elementary divisors of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

From Advanced Modern Algebra (Rotman):

> **Proposition 4.10** If $G$ is an abelian group and $p$ is prime, then $G/pG$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_p.$
>
> **Definition** If $p$ is prime and $G$ is a finite $p$-primary abelian group, then $$d(G)=\dim(G/pG).$$
>
> **Definition** Let $G$ be a finite $p$-primary abelian group, where $p$ is prime. For $n \geq 0$,  define $$U_p(n,G) = d(p^n,G) - d(p^{n+1}, G).$$

The textbook says that when we decompose a finite $p$-primary abelian group into factors, $U_p(n,G)$ will be "the number of cyclic summands having order $p^{n+1}$".

> **Definition** If $G$ is a $p$-primary abelian group, then its ***elementary divisors*** are the numbers in the sequence $ U_p(0,G)$ $p'$s, $U_p(1, G)$ $p^2$'s, ... , $U_p(t-1,G)$ $p^t$'s

Then the textbook gives an example: decomposing an abelian group of order $72=2^33^2$.

Basically, you just say $8 = (2)(4) = (2)(2)(2)$ and $(9)=(3)(3)$, and you have the elementary divisors, right? But I don't know how to relate this to the method that Rotman uses.

In other words (for example), we have $U_2(0,G)$ $2$'s, and $U_2(0,G) = \dim(G/2G) - \dim(2G/4G)$.

$\{0+2G, 1+2G\}$ is a basis for $G/2G$, so $\dim(G/2G)=2$

and

$\{0+2G, 2+2G\}$ is a basis for $2G/4G$, so $\dim(2G/4G)=2$, right?

But then $U_2(0,G)=0$???

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean "decompose" a group of order $72$? There are multiple isomorphism types of abelian groups of that order.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I don't know if I used the wrong vocabulary. I just meant "how many abelian groups of order 72 are there?".

Comment: This seems like a very strange way of answering this question. You don't need the elementary factors to answer this. In general, if $m=p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_\ell^{n_\ell}$ then the number of abelian groups of order $m$ is $P(n_1)\cdots P(n_\ell)$ where $P$ is the partition function. For example, for $72=2^23^2$ you get $P(2)^2=2^2=4$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks a lot. But I was trying to understand how I could relate this problem to the theorems. In other words, my main goal is to be able to relate it to the theorems rather than actually answering the question.  I was just using this problem as an example...

Comment: What is $d(p^n,G)$ ?

Comment: @BorisNovikov $d(p^nG) = \dim(p^nG/p^{n+1}G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have $G=H\oplus K$ where $|H|=8$ and $|K|=9$. Then apply the Rotman's method to the **primary** groups  $H$ and $K$.

**Addendum:** For example, take the group $G={\mathbb Z}_2\oplus {\mathbb Z}_2^2$. For it the elementary divisors are $(2,4)$. We have $G/2G={\mathbb Z}_2, 2G/4G={\mathbb Z}_2$, so $\dim(G/2G)= \dim(2G/4G)=1$ (since a basis for $G/2G$ is $\{1+2G\}$!). This means $U_2(0,G)=U_2(1,G)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I was trying to do. For the 2-primary group H, the last definition says that the number of elementary divisors of order 2 is $U_p(0,G)$ and the number of elementary divisors of order $2^2$ is $U_p(1,G)$. That's what I was trying to compute but couldn't...

Comment: I extended the answer. Please ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that Rotman is using all of this machinery to prove the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, but sometimes to understand the intuition, it is best to assume the result of the theorem, and work through a general example.

What I mean is this: let us begin with a finite abelian $p$ primary group $G$, which we 'know' is a product of cyclic groups.  Write $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_1}}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_m}}$, with all $k_i\ge 1$.  Now, multiplication by $p$ will kill off a power of $p$ in each summand, so we have:

$$pG\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_1-1}}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_m-1}}$$

Notice that some of these summands may be trivial (if $k_i=1$), and we are interested in determining the number of them that are, which we'll 'call' $U_p(0,G)$.  The quotient space is:

$$G/pG\cong \underbrace{\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p}}_{m\text{ times}}$$

Notice this has dimension $m$ as an $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space, so that $d(G)=m$.  Let's now compute $p^2G$:

$$p^2G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_1-2}}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_m-2}}$$

Some of these summands may not make sense, specifically those for which $k_i=1$.  For notational purposes, we leave them in the direct sum, understanding that they are just the identity.  For each $k_i=1$, we have, in our notation, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_i-1}}/\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_i-2}}=\{e\}$.  This means that $d(p,G)$, the dimension of the quotient:

$$pG/p^2G=\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p}_{D(p,G)\text{ many times}}$$

is exactly $U_p(0,G)$ less than $d(G)$, one for each summand of $G$ with $k_i=1$.  We thus arrive at the formula $U_p(0,G)=d(G)-d(p,G)$.

Now just repeat the argument replacing $G$ with $pG$, and noting that $d(p^n,pG)=d(p^{n+1},G)$ and $U_p(n,pG)=U_p(n+1,G)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I tried to apply this to an example and kind of got confused. Let's say that $G \cong \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^2} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^4} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^5}$. Then $3G \cong \{e\} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^3} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^4}$. So $U(0,G)=1$, since there is only one identity as a summand. Since $G/3G \cong \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_3$, we have $d(G)=4$. Now $9G \cong \{e\} \oplus \{e\} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^2} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3^3}$. So $3G/9G \cong \Bbb{Z}_3 \oplus \Bbb{Z}_3$. So $d(9G)=2$, but $d(G) - U(0,G) = 4 - 1 =3$.

Comment: @Artus:  Great idea to use a more concrete example.  Everything you do is fine, except I think that $3G/9G\cong\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ so that $d(3,G)=3$, as it should.  It follows that $U_3(0,G)=d(G)-d(3,G)=4-3=1$.  Continuing on, you'll find that $9G/27G\cong\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$, so that $d(9,G)=2$ and thus $U_3(1,G)=d(3,G)-d(9,G)=3-2=1$.